# find duplicates with grouped variables

Tags: r, duplicates, identify

I have a df that looks like this:

I guess it will work some with dplyr and duplicates. Yet I don't know how to address multiple columns while distinguishing between a grouped variable.

```
from  to  group

1     2   metro
2     4   metro
3     4   metro
4     5   train
6     1   train
8     7   train
```

I want to find the `ids` which exist in more than one `group` variable.

The expected result for the sample `df` is: `1` and `4`. Because they exist in the metro and the train group.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `gather` the 'from', 'to' columns to 'long' format, grouped by 'val', `filter` the groups having more than one unique elements, then `pull` the unique 'val' elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   gather(key, val, from:to) %>% 
   group_by(val) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(group) > 1) %>%
   distinct(val) %>%
   pull(val)
#[1] 1 4
```

---

Or using `base R` we can just `table` to find the frequency, and get the ids out of it

```
out <-  with(df1, colSums(table(rep(group, 2), unlist(df1[1:2])) > 0)) > 1
names(which(out))
#[1] "1" "4"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(from = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 8L), to = c(2L, 4L, 
 4L, 5L, 1L, 7L), group = c("metro", "metro", "metro", "train", 
 "train", "train")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
 ))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using base R we can `split` the first two columns based on `group` and find the intersecting value between the groups using `intersect`

```
Reduce(intersect, split(unlist(df[1:2]), df$group))
#[1] 1 4
```

Comment: Love the `Reduce` function. Nice 1!

Answer (score 1):

Convert data to long format and count unique values, using `data.table`. `melt` is used to convert to long format, and data table allows filtering in the `i` part of `df1[ i, j, k]`, grouping in the `k` part, and `pull`ing in the `j` part.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(df1)

melt(df1, 'group') %>% 
  .[, .(n = uniqueN(group)), value] %>% 
  .[n > 1, unique(value)]

# [1] 1 4
```